# Using SQL Server 2008 R2 to query Progress OpenEdge10.2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, openedge, progress-db

We just acquired a company that has some apps running on Progress. We're a Microsoft shop and need to query the data from SQL Server (in the short term). We have the following ODBC drivers installed on SQL Server, but they don't show up when I try to add a link server, or as a provider under linked servers:

32-bit

[image: 32-bit]

64-bit

[image: 64-bit]

When I go to Linked Servers, I see this. I've never done anything with providers, so not sure if I need to add something.

[image: Linked Servers and Providers]

The IT Guy there connects in VB.net using a connection string like this, but never got SQL to connect:

```
Driver={Progress OpenEdge 10.2B Driver};uid=USERNAME;host=HOSTNAME;db=DBNAME;port=2701;pwd=!PASSWORD
```

I tried using this as a connection string, but no luck.

Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an ODBC driver, so focus on `Microsoft OLE DB for ODBC Drivers`

Here's an example for a DSN (Data Source Name) called 'Service Now'. That could be any database, probably not Progress, but a DSN is  DSN.

http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=Using_ODBC_Driver_in_SQL_Server_2008_and_2012

Create a DSN (in the system DSN tab of ODBCAD32) for your Progress database and reference it as in these examples.

Of course the bitness of your DSN needs to match the bitness of your SQL Server.

*WARNING:*

Using linked servers over unreliable ODBC drivers will give you headaches. You should test this thoroughly and be aware that in many cases if you, for example, join two tables over a linked sever, all of the data from the two tables will be dragged over and joined on the SQL Server. You can use `OpenRowset` to alleviate this as it lets you write pass through queries over a linked server.

You need to ensure that this really is a temporary measure!

Comment: Thanks. Just trying to locate 64 bit odbc driver

Answer (score 1):

Try this entry from the Progress Knowledgebase - http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P97292

If this doesn't suit, then you can search the KB for other options.

Comment: Thanks. Just trying to get hold of the 64-bit ODBC driver

Comment: If your application is under maintenance, then contact Progress tech support - they'd get a definitive answer for you.

Comment: Thanks. I got the driver and license and it works great. Only issue is that you can't store the password in the DSN, so I had to use a connection string in addition to the DSN name when setting up the linked server, as this is the only way I could see to save the password